# React Native: how to handle state for each item in a rendered FlatList when pressing the 'like' button?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, setstate

I'm trying to handle the state for a 'heart' icon in a rendered Flat List (which loads data from Firebase) for each individual item within the Flat List.

The code works, in that the heart icon fills in and the data is pushed to the database when the icon is pressed. Likewise, pressing the heart icon again reverts the icon and removes the 'like' from the database.

However, when the heart icon is clicked, it swaps between the filled in state and hollow state for the heart icon for **every** item in the list, when I'm trying to alter state for that specific item.

I understand that I need to handle state locally for each item in the Flat List, but I've no idea how to do it. Any help would be appreciated. Code below:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
  FlatList,
  Text,
  View,
} from 'react-native';
import {Icon} from 'react-native-elements';
import {globalStyles} from '../config/Styles';
import Firebase from 'firebase';
import 'firebase/database';

export default class HomeScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      //set value of postList variable as an empty array
      postList: [],
      liked: false,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getPostData();
  }

  getPostData = () => {
    const ref = Firebase.database().ref('/posts');
    ref.on('value', snapshot => {
      const postsObject = snapshot.val();
      if (!postsObject) {
        console.log('NO DATA IN FIREBASE:', Date(Date.now()));
      } else {
        console.log('HOMESCREEN FIREBASE DATA RETRIEVED:', Date(Date.now()));
        const postsArray = Object.values(postsObject);
        this.setState({postList: postsArray});
      }
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <FlatList
          keyExtractor={post => post.id}
          data={this.state.postList}
          renderItem={({item: post}) => (
            <View style={globalStyles.postContainer}>
              <Text style={globalStyles.postText}>
                {post.heading}
                {'\n'}@{' '}
                <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>{post.location}</Text>
                {'\n'}
                {post.description}
                {'\n'}
                listed by{' '}
                <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>{post.createdBy}</Text>
                {'\n'}
                on <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>{post.createdAt}</Text>
              </Text>
              <View style={globalStyles.iconMargin}>
                <Icon
                  raised
                  iconStyle={globalStyles.icon}
                  name={this.state.liked ? 'heart' : 'heart-o'}
                  size={28}
                  type="font-awesome"
                  onPress={() => {
                    const userKey = Firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
                    const postKey = post.id;
                    const favRef = Firebase.database().ref(
                      'favourites/' + userKey + '/' + postKey,
                    );
                    if (this.state.liked === false) {
                      favRef.set({
                        id: postKey,
                        heading: post.heading,
                        description: post.description,
                        location: post.location,
                        createdAt: post.createdAt,
                        createdBy: post.createdBy,
                      });
                      this.setState({liked: true});
                    } else {
                      favRef.remove();
                      this.setState({liked: false});
                    }
                  }}
                />
                <Icon
                  raised
                  iconStyle={globalStyles.icon}
                  name="flag-o"
                  size={28}
                  type="font-awesome"
                  onPress={() =>
                    this.props.navigation.navigate('ReportPostScreen', post)
                  }
                />
              </View>
            </View>
          )}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the issue is that you've got a singular `liked` state value instead of an array. You should firstly change `liked` to an array (which will store the id of the posts which are liked). Maybe call it something more appropriate such as `likePosts`. Then you can add or remove post ids from the array when they're liked or unliked (and check the `likedPosts` array for the value when deciding what icon to display).

Your modified code should look something like this:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
  FlatList,
  Text,
  View,
} from 'react-native';
import {Icon} from 'react-native-elements';
import {globalStyles} from '../config/Styles';
import Firebase from 'firebase';
import 'firebase/database';

export default class HomeScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      //set value of postList variable as an empty array
      postList: [],
      likedPosts: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getPostData();
  }

  getPostData = () => {
    const ref = Firebase.database().ref('/posts');
    ref.on('value', snapshot => {
      const postsObject = snapshot.val();
      if (!postsObject) {
        console.log('NO DATA IN FIREBASE:', Date(Date.now()));
      } else {
        console.log('HOMESCREEN FIREBASE DATA RETRIEVED:', Date(Date.now()));
        const postsArray = Object.values(postsObject);
        this.setState({postList: postsArray});
      }
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <FlatList
          keyExtractor={post => post.id}
          data={this.state.postList}
          renderItem={({item: post}) => (
            <View style={globalStyles.postContainer}>
              <Text style={globalStyles.postText}>
                {post.heading}
                {'\n'}@{' '}
                <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>{post.location}</Text>
                {'\n'}
                {post.description}
                {'\n'}
                listed by{' '}
                <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>{post.createdBy}</Text>
                {'\n'}
                on <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>{post.createdAt}</Text>
              </Text>
              <View style={globalStyles.iconMargin}>
                <Icon
                  raised
                  iconStyle={globalStyles.icon}
                  name={this.state.likedPosts.indexOf(post.id) > -1 ? 'heart' : 'heart-o'}
                  size={28}
                  type="font-awesome"
                  onPress={() => {
                    const userKey = Firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
                    const postKey = post.id;
                    const favRef = Firebase.database().ref(
                      'favourites/' + userKey + '/' + postKey,
                    );

                    // This checks that the array doesn't contain the post id (i.e. the post was not previously liked)
                    if (this.state.likedPosts.indexOf(post.id) === -1) {
                      favRef.set({
                        id: postKey,
                        heading: post.heading,
                        description: post.description,
                        location: post.location,
                        createdAt: post.createdAt,
                        createdBy: post.createdBy,
                      });
                      // Include the post.id in the likedPosts array
                      this.setState({ likedPosts: [...this.state.likedPosts, post.id] })
                    } else {
                      favRef.remove();
                      // Remove the post.id from the likedPosts array
                      let index = this.state.likedPosts.indexOf(post.id);
                      this.setState({ likedPosts: this.state.likedPosts.splice(index, 1) })
                    }
                  }}
                />
                <Icon
                  raised
                  iconStyle={globalStyles.icon}
                  name="flag-o"
                  size={28}
                  type="font-awesome"
                  onPress={() =>
                    this.props.navigation.navigate('ReportPostScreen', post)
                  }
                />
              </View>
            </View>
          )}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: put then when he retrives the post from api he will not know if it is liked or not because it is empty state array

Comment: The data that's being fetched is different from the data that's being pushed for likes (`Firebase.database().ref('/posts')` for fetch vs `Firebase.database().ref('favourites/' + userKey + '/' + postKey)` for liked items). So that doesn't seem to be a use case here (displaying previously liked items from the database).

Comment: Thanks for the help @Jono. Liking a post now fills the heart ONLY for that post. However, when unliking a post, all of the posts are unliked - though, I'm sure I can figure this out. I would also like to show previously liked items from the database as well, but I didn't include this in my original post as I wanted to make sure I got the individual likes to work first.

Comment: Again, thank you for help. Found a solution to the unlike problem with the following code in the else statement:
`//array item is first spliced before the array is re-rendered
this.state.likedPosts.splice(index, 1);
this.setState({
likedPosts: this.state.likedPosts,
});
}`

Comment: Glad it worked, and a pleasure to help. Ah I see what the issue with removal of like was, there was a rogue `]` in my code. Edited so it should work now, but glad to hear you got it sorted! Makes sense to initialise a new array from liked posts with item removed, then set your new state to that new array.

Answer (score 0):

becuase this.state.liked will be true for all items in the json respone
to correct it you can update the state array json

```
 ItemPRessed =(index)=>{let dataArray = this.state.data
  dataArray[index].liked = !dataArray[index].liked
  this.setState({
    data:dataArray
  })}
```

and instead of `this.state.liked` use `post.liked` so it will be specific to the item
and instead of                       `this.setState({liked: true});`
put

```
this.ItemPRessed(Index)
```

i don't know how your indexs work in your json put if it is like this

```
[{item},{item}]
```

then you can use `renderItem=({item: post, index})` instead of `renderItem={({item: post})`

to get the index on which item it is pressed then